# Can (and how) KVM use NTFS storage?

Tags: kvm, ntfs

Using SL6.4, I am trying to create a new KVM virtual machine using `virt-manager`. When defining storage at default pool, it boots up OK. However, when trying to use storage located on external NTFS drive, it fails with permission denied.

I've changed SElinux to permissive mode, defined a directory on the NTFS drive as storage pool; (un)commented the "user" and "group" lines on `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` file, but none of these helped.

Should something with the NTFS mounting be changed?
Maybe some other configuration?

EDIT:

virt-manager succeeded creating .img file on the NTFS partition (but warned me that it doesn't have search permission (??) in that directory), it failed only when trying to start the virtual machine.

Furthermore, if I try to use default storage, and read an ISO file from /home partition - it works; but when I try to use default storage and read an ISO file from NTFS partition it fails with the same failure.
(the ISO file is readable from the NTFS partition. I know that because it was copied from there to /home ...)

Comment: NTFS doesn't support UNIX permissions.

Comment: let's rule out KVM first - can you add a file on this NTFS volume under Linux?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. When starting VM using image stored on shared NTFS partition, I was getting:

```
Could not open '/path/to.qed': Permission denied
```

It was not a problem related to mounting the drive, but to SELinux. `journalctl -xf` revealed SELinux problem:

```
paź 05 08:45:20 everfree.forest setroubleshoot[10798]: SELinux is preventing qemu-system-x86 from open access on the file /path/to.qed. For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l 0aaa735d-23e9-4205-b024-8b56a2b9c473
...
*****  Plugin catchall_boolean (89.3 confidence) suggests   ******************

If you want to allow confined virtual guests to read fuse files
Then you must tell SELinux about this by enabling the 'virt_use_fusefs' boolean.

Do
setsebool -P virt_use_fusefs 1
```

Setting the SELinux boolean fixed my problem.

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). It would be nice to know _exactly_ what consequences that command has.

Comment: What would be the equivalent of `setsebool -P virt_use_fusefs 1` on Ubuntu with apparmor?

Answer (score 1):

I received permissions error when accessing storage pools in NTFS storage. (OS - `Ubuntu 22.04`) Here is how I fixed this error:

- So in my fstab, I mounted the ntfs partition with following options `defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,dmask=027,fmask=117,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names`. Here https://askubuntu.com/questions/113733/how-to-mount-a-ntfs-partition-in-etc-fstab is more detailed answer.
- The `uid` and `gid` was of my current user using `id` command.
- The `fmask=117` options make files `rw` by user and `rw` by group and no permissions to others.

After this I added `libvirt-qemu` to my group, i.e. `sudo usermod -aG $(whoami) libvirt-qemu`. This fixed the permissions error.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, with information from https://askubuntu.com/questions/113733/how-do-i-correctly-mount-a-ntfs-partition-in-etc-fstab :

Just add 'permissions' to the mount command, and everything works.

Thanks!

Comment: How does adding the word `permissions` to the mount command help? I can't find this documented anywhere, and not in that linked Q&A either. It says something else entirely.